# displaying DIV using Javascript and getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>GPM ConnectionModul Systems Configuration</TITLE>
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="GPM_SFTPConnector.css" type="text/css">

    <script>


        function systemAnzeigen(systemid) {
            var elms = document.getElementsByClassName("connectionClass");

            for (i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
                if (elms.item(i).id == systemid) {
                    elms.item(i).style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    elms.item(i).style.display = 'none';
                }

            }
        }


        function systemAendern(systemid) {
            alert("System aendern: " + systemid);
        }

        function systemLöschen(systemid) {
            alert("System loeschen: " + systemid);
        }

    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

    <strong>Error listing systems: </strong> [ISC.0049.9009] Missing required property switch at 'unlabeled BRANCH'<P>

        <strong>Konfigurierete Systeme</strong>

        <TABLE class="GPMTable" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:small">
            <TR>
                <TH>System-ID</TH>
                <TH>Ändern</TH>
                <TH>Löschen</TH>
            </TR>

            <TR>
                <TD><a href="javascript:systemAnzeigen('system1');">system1</a></TD>
                <TD><img onclick="javascript: systemAendern('system1');" src="edit.gif" /></TD>
                <TD><img onclick="javascript: systemLoeschen('system1');" src="delete.gif" /></TD>
            </TR>

            <TR>
                <TD><a href="javascript:systemAnzeigen('system2');">system2</a></TD>
                <TD><img onclick="javascript: systemAendern('system2');" src="edit.gif" /></TD>
                <TD><img onclick="javascript: systemLoeschen('system2');" src="delete.gif" /></TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>


        <div class="connectionClass" id="system1" style="display: none;">

            <h4>system1</h4>

            <TABLE class="GPMTable" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:small">
                <TR>
                    <TH>Connection-ID</TH>
                    <TH>Protokoll</TH>
                    <TH>Mapping</TH>
                </TR>

                <TR>
                    <TD>poller1</TD>
                    <TD>SFTP</TD>
                    <TD></TD>

                </TR>

                <TR>
                    <TD>soapConnection1</TD>
                    <TD>SOAP</TD>
                    <TD>mymapping</TD>

                </TR>
            </TABLE>

            <div class="connectionClass" id="system2" style="display: none;">

                <h4>system2</h4>

                <TABLE class="GPMTable" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:small">
                    <TR>
                        <TH>Connection-ID</TH>
                        <TH>Protokoll</TH>
                        <TH>Mapping</TH>
                    </TR>

                    <TR>
                        <TD>RestConnection1</TD>
                        <TD>REST</TD>
                        <TD></TD>

                    </TR>
                </TABLE>
            </div>

    <P><a href="index.html">Home</a><P>
```

The DIV with ID "system1" perfectly displays, when the link named "system1" is clicked. However, when clicking the link named "system2" the DIV with ID "system2" is not displayed.

Can someone explain, why this is not working and how to make it work?

Comment: I guess `elms.item(i)` should be `elms[i]`, in any case rule of thumb is to create a fiddle and put some effort into your question

Comment: There's a lot wrong with that HTML but the answer to your question is that you're missing a closing `</div>`

Comment: You didn't close your div tag from `system1` so if you go to the DOM inspector, you'll see that `system2` is embedded within the `system1` div.

Comment: Since you are working with Ids, why don't you get eelement with `var elem = document.getElementById(systemid);` and then `elem.style.display = 'block';` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never close the `<div id="system1">` tag, so `<div id="system2">` is actually *inside* it. Everything in `system1` (including `system2`) is hidden when `system2` link is clicked.

Add

```
</div>
```

right before

```
<div class="connectionClass" id="system2" style="display: none;">
```

```html
<script>
  function systemAnzeigen(systemid) {
    var elms = document.getElementsByClassName("connectionClass");

    for (i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
      if (elms.item(i).id == systemid) {
        elms.item(i).style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        elms.item(i).style.display = 'none';
      }

    }
  }


  function systemAendern(systemid) {
    alert("System aendern: " + systemid);
  }

  function systemLöschen(systemid) {
    alert("System loeschen: " + systemid);
  }
</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

  <strong>Error listing systems: </strong> [ISC.0049.9009] Missing required property switch at 'unlabeled BRANCH'
  <P>

    <strong>Konfigurierete Systeme</strong>

    <TABLE class="GPMTable" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:small">
      <TR>
        <TH>System-ID</TH>
        <TH>Ändern</TH>
        <TH>Löschen</TH>
      </TR>

      <TR>
        <TD><a href="javascript:systemAnzeigen('system1');">system1</a>
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <img onclick="javascript:systemAendern('system1');" src="edit.gif" />
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <img onclick="javascript:systemLoeschen('system1');" src="delete.gif" />
        </TD>
      </TR>

      <TR>
        <TD><a href="javascript:systemAnzeigen('system2');">system2</a>
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <img onclick="javascript:systemAendern('system2');" src="edit.gif" />
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <img onclick="javascript:systemLoeschen('system2');" src="delete.gif" />
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>


    <div class="connectionClass" id="system1" style="display: none;">

      <h4>system1</h4>

      <TABLE class="GPMTable" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:small">
        <TR>
          <TH>Connection-ID</TH>
          <TH>Protokoll</TH>
          <TH>Mapping</TH>
        </TR>

        <TR>
          <TD>poller1</TD>
          <TD>SFTP</TD>
          <TD></TD>

        </TR>

        <TR>
          <TD>soapConnection1</TD>
          <TD>SOAP</TD>
          <TD>mymapping</TD>

        </TR>
      </TABLE>

    </div>
    <div class="connectionClass" id="system2" style="display: none;">

      <h4>system2</h4>

      <TABLE class="GPMTable" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:small">
        <TR>
          <TH>Connection-ID</TH>
          <TH>Protokoll</TH>
          <TH>Mapping</TH>
        </TR>

        <TR>
          <TD>RestConnection1</TD>
          <TD>REST</TD>
          <TD></TD>

        </TR>
      </TABLE>
    </div>

    <P><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <P>
```

Comment: And we're downvoting because...?

Answer (score 3):

Using Visual Studio it shows me that

```
<div class="connectionClass" id="system1" style="display: none;">`
```

is missing it's closing tag `</div>`. I assume you want to put the `</div>` just before the system2 tag:

```
<div class="connectionClass" id="system2" style="display: none;">
```

Missing Tags will cause Layout problems

For debugging JavaScript make sure to use the Browsers Console on wich any errors will be shown (Press F12)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not have any understanding of Umlaut.

So in JavaScript, `systemLoeschen` and `systemLöschen` are NOT the same.

It would be a good idea to keep your function names in English. Partially to avoid such issues (I've had to give this advice to more than a few French programmers...) but also because the keywords of the language itself are already in English and it just makes sense to stick to it.

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML markup is wrong. From what I see it's rendering "system2" inside "system1" div, so when you hide "system1" it will also hide its children ("system2")

```html
<TITLE>GPM ConnectionModul Systems Configuration</TITLE>
<script>
    function systemAnzeigen(systemid) {
        var elms = document.getElementsByClassName("connectionClass");

        for (i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
            if (elms.item(i).id == systemid) {
                elms.item(i).style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                elms.item(i).style.display = 'none';
            }

        }
    }


    function systemAendern(systemid) {
        alert("System aendern: " + systemid);
    }

    function systemLöschen(systemid) {
        alert("System loeschen: " + systemid);
    }
</script>
<BODY> <strong>Error listing systems: </strong> [ISC.0049.9009] Missing required property switch at 'unlabeled BRANCH'
    <P>
<strong>Konfigurierete Systeme</strong>

        <TABLE class="GPMTable" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:small">
            <TR>
                <TH>System-ID</TH>
                <TH>Ändern</TH>
                <TH>Löschen</TH>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD><a href="javascript:systemAnzeigen('system1');">system1</a>
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <img onclick="javascript:systemAendern('system1');" src="edit.gif" />
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <img onclick="javascript:systemLoeschen('system1');" src="delete.gif" />
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD><a href="javascript:systemAnzeigen('system2');">system2</a>
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <img onclick="javascript:systemAendern('system2');" src="edit.gif" />
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <img onclick="javascript:systemLoeschen('system2');" src="delete.gif" />
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
        <div class="connectionClass" id="system1" style="display: none;">
            
<h4>system1</h4>

            <TABLE class="GPMTable" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:small">
                <TR>
                    <TH>Connection-ID</TH>
                    <TH>Protokoll</TH>
                    <TH>Mapping</TH>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>poller1</TD>
                    <TD>SFTP</TD>
                    <TD></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>soapConnection1</TD>
                    <TD>SOAP</TD>
                    <TD>mymapping</TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </div>
        
        <div class="connectionClass" id="system2" style="display: none;">
                
                <h4>system2</h4>

                <TABLE class="GPMTable" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:small">
                    <TR>
                        <TH>Connection-ID</TH>
                        <TH>Protokoll</TH>
                        <TH>Mapping</TH>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD>RestConnection1</TD>
                        <TD>REST</TD>
                        <TD></TD>
                    </TR>
                </TABLE>
            </div>
```